# Are there situations where fractions can be used consistently with modular arithmetic?

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Let $a,b,c,q,r$ be integers such that:

- $\frac{a}{b} > 1$ and $gcd(a,b)=1$
- $b > 1$ and $b | c$
- $a = qb+r$

Does it follow that:

$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)c \equiv \left(\frac{r}{b}\right)c\pmod c$$

Here's an example of what I am talking about:

Let $a=12, b=5, c=30$ so that we have:

$$\left(\frac{12}{5}\right)30 = 72 \equiv 12 \pmod {30}$$

But also:

$$\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)30 = 12$$

Here's my reasoning for why this should always work:

> Let $d = \frac{c}{b}$ so that $ad = (qb+r)d = qbd + rd = qc + rd \equiv rd \pmod {c}$

I ask this here because I never see a mention about fractions with regard to modular arithmetic.  I want to make sure that I am not missing some obvious mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the question to remove the word "question".

Comment: Since you assume $b|c$, then $\frac{a}{b}c$ is always an integer, so not really a fraction.

Comment: Got it.  Since it has a consistent non-fraction form, it is not a fraction.

Comment: Inverses (sometimes written as fractions) in modular arithmetic whenever the denominator is relatively prime to the modulus.  So, there is a partial answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If $\frac{a}{b}$ makes sense*, then yes, what you have written is correct. Here's why: $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)c = \left(\frac{bq+r}{b}\right)c = bc + \frac{r}{b}c$, and $bc \equiv 0\mod{c}$.

However, using fractions is really not the right way to think about things. $\frac{1}{b}$ does not always make sense. In fact, in your example, $\frac{12}{5} = 12\cdot\frac{1}{5}$, and $\frac{1}{5}$ does not make sense modulo $30$. Why? Well, $\frac{1}{5}$ should be some residue class modulo $30$, say $a$, such that $5a\equiv 1\mod{30}$ (that's what it means to be a multiplicative inverse). But this is impossible, since if such a residue class existed, then $5a = 1 + 30k$, so that $5a-30k = 1$. But $\gcd(5,30) = 5$ and this cannot be.

In general, $\frac{1}{b}$, or $b^{-1}$, is meaningful only if $\gcd(b,c) = 1$.